# On a complement of an open set of a circle in $\Bbb{R}^{3}:$Path connected

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $C$ be a unit circle in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$, so it can be identified to $\{(x,y,0):(x,y)\in S^1\}.$

Now I have $$C_1:=\{(x,y,0)\in\Bbb{R^3}:(x,y)\in S^1 \land (y>-a)\}$$ $$C_2:=\{(x,y,0)\in\Bbb{R^3}:(x,y)\in S^1 \land (y<a)\}.$$ for $0<a<1.$

Denote $U_1=\Bbb{R}\times(-a,+\infty)\times\Bbb{R}$ and so $V_1=U_1\setminus{C_1}.$

I would like to prove that $V_1$ is path connected.

So let $u=(x,y,z)$ and $v=(x',y',z')$ be in it. If there are "strictly outside" of $C_1,$ no problem, as well as if there are "strictly inside."

We can suppose that one is "strictly inside" and the other one "strictly outside". It's intuitively obvious that we can relies them by a path: we are in $\Bbb{R^3}!$

But to formalize it it's anther problem I may introduce a the rotation matrix of $y-$axis noted $R_y(\theta)$ and composed it **but how ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following. Using the fact that the relation of two points being connected by a path is transitive.

- If $P\in V_1$ has $z$-coordinate $\ge0$, then the straight line from $P$ to $Q_1=(0,0,1)$ is entirely in $V_1$.
- If $P\in V_1$ has $z$-coordinate $\le0$, then the straight line from $P$ to $Q_2=(0,0,-1)$ is entirely in $V_1$.
- The straight line connecting $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ is entirely in $V_1$.
- Therefore any pair of points $P_1,P_2$ in $V_1$ can be joined by a polygonal path in $V_1$. Either via $Q_1$, $Q_2$ or both.

Comment: arf yes I did't think to use the transitive property. Thank you!